# Using Memory Allocated by Different Allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocator

Suppose I have a class called `vector` that maintains some internal, dynamic array of type `T` allocated by `std::allocator<T>.` Now, I construct a `vector` of type `U`, and later want to use move semantics so that I can use the memory consumed by it for a `vector` of type `T`, like so:

```
vector<unsigned> u(512);
// Do something with v.
vector<double> t = std::move(u);
// Do something with t.
// Later, t gets destroyed.
```

Is it safe for me to use the memory allocated by `u`'s allocator in `t`'s move constructor, and later deallocate it using `t`'s allocator? If so, what would I have to do to ensure that this operation would be safe? I'm guessing that I should first call `allocator.destroy()` for each element of `u`'s internal array using `u`'s allocator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is one of the purposed designs of the STL, that memory allocated by one allocator can be deallocated by another. This is because they wanted to be able to swap elements between containers (such as with `list::splice`) without having to do anything with their allocators. That is (one of the reasons) why you can't really have stateful allocators.

Comment: C++11 allows stateful allocators. You just need to define a few extra functions IIRC.

Comment: @Xeo C++11 to the rescue again. Can you provide a link on how to do that? I'd definitely like to know.